# Why can I ignore this part of the circuit during step response analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, step-response

I'm doing a RL step response analysis problem and I am confused on why we are able to only consider the left side of the circuit when the switch moves from position a to position b.

"The switch in the circuit below has been in position a for a long time. At time t=0, the switch is moved to position b"

I attached a picture of the given circuit and a picture of my drawing of what I think is happening with the current (current is blue highlighter).

If my drawing is correct, why can we ignore the right side?
If my drawing is incorrect, how does the current really behave and why can we ignore the right side?

[image: picture of my drawing]

[image: given circuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inductor current after t=0 continue to flow the same way as the inductor was charged from 8A current source, but the it is continuously recharged to opposite direction from 24V source to -12A.
So your drawn current direction is valid in steady state only (or at t>50ms).
You can ignore the right side because after t=0 the right side does not affect the inductor current.

*(The switch is activated at 200ms in simulation)*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsR3t5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]